# system() takes at most 1 argument (2 given), trying to pass argument from user

Tags: python, python-3.x, os.system

```
    user = input("enter target account:")
    if inp==1:
        os.system("adb shell monkey -p com.instagram.android -v 1")
        time.sleep(1)
        os.system("adb shell input tap 328 2200")
        time.sleep(1)
        os.system("adb shell input tap 500 178")
        time.sleep(1)
        os.system("adb shell input text user")
        time.sleep(1.5)
```

When someone writes the name, it does not print it, it prints user
and I try to make

```
    os.system("adb shell input text", user)
```

but its show me this erorr

```
system() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)
```

Comment: (that said, you shouldn't be using `os.system()` at all in new code; `subprocess.call()` with the default `shell=False` and an argument vector in place of an argument string is much safer, particularly if you need to pass through arbitrary arguments)

Comment: If what you want is `f"adb shell input text {user}"`, that's the exact kind of seriously-insecure thing I was warning you about.

Comment: ...think about what happens if the user says the target account is `$(rm -rf ~)`, keeping in mind that the text is evaluated by a shell _on your computer_ before it gets to a shell on the target Android device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run the following, you are not passing the `user` variable to your command.

```py
os.system("adb shell input text user")
```

The following will not work as per the error you got, [`os.system()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) takes a single argument.

```py
os.system("adb shell input text", user)
```

You can do the following, **but you *really* should not as it allows [code injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection)**.

```py
os.system(f"adb shell input text {user}")
```

Plus you can read the following from the documentation of[`os.system()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system).

> The [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module provides more powerful facilities for spawning new processes and retrieving their results; using that module is preferable to using this function. See the [Replacing Older Functions with the subprocess Module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess-replacements) section in the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) documentation for some helpful recipes.

So, instead you can use the following (credits to Charles Duffy):

```
subprocess.call(["adb", "shell", "input", "text", user])
```

Which is your command split by [`shlex.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.split) with a safe `user` variable passed and run by [`subprocess.call()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call).

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `os.system()`; use `subprocess.call()` instead.

```
subprocess.call(['adb', 'shell', 'input', 'text', user])
```

Comment: From [`os.system()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) documentation: The [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module provides more powerful facilities for spawning new processes and retrieving their results; using that module is preferable to using this function. See the [Replacing Older Functions with the subprocess Module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess-replacements) section in the subprocess documentation for some helpful recipes.

Comment: @ljmc This answer is community wiki, so please move your comment to the answer to make it more visible.